# How to for loop months and year between two dates

Tags: php, laravel

**How to for loop months and year between two dates with given intervals in laravel**

Comment: Please make sure to add content to your question and accept the answer if it solves what you need

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a place to just drop off your questions, and letting someone else do the work for you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [CarbonPeriod](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period) class todo same

```
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

$from = '2019-01-01';
$to = '2020-04-01';
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($from, '1 month', $to);
    
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("Y-m") . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: i need to get more than one year difference in dates

Comment: Yes, You can add from date and to date as per your requirement.