# Getting months from now and a couple of months ago

Tags: laravel

What I'm trying to do get the month names from this month all the way to last year, but I'm not sure how to get that.

I've got

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$past = Carbon::now()->subMonths(4);
```

but I don't think that is correct.

Comment: So you want to get `November`, `October`, `...`, `January`, `December`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494135/how-to-for-loop-months-and-year-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

you can use DatePeriod from Carbon, simply get the DatePeriod From the very first of the year to now, using DateInterval as month:

```
 $value=collect(
          new DatePeriod(Carbon::now()->firstOfYear(), new DateInterval('P1M'),Carbon::now() ))->map(function ($month) {
          return $month->format('M');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CarbonPeriod` class todo same

```
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

$oneYearAgo = new CarbonPeriod('2020-03-08', '1 month', '2021-03-08');

foreach ($oneYearAgo as $month) {
    $month->format("M"); //Mar
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period).